# A method for $y^{IV}-xy''-y'+y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have a differential equation of order four:
$$
  y^{IV}-xy''-y'+y=0.
$$
and initial conditions
$$
  \begin{array}{ll}
    y(0)=0, & y'(0)=1; \\
    y(1)=0, & y'(1)=-\sinh1.
  \end{array}
$$
I tried substitution $y=e^{\int z dx}$, but it becomes even worse (maybe because of some silly technical mistake). Any suggestions for the method, please.

Comment: You can use Laplace transform but I think initial conditions need!

Comment: @MyGlasses, thanks for reply, actually I have some initial conditions. But what can we do with those conditions?

Comment: Method: `Numeric`.

Comment: You can use Frobenius' method.